# Transform 2 Exact Pojos but with different namespaces in a generic fashion

Tags: java

I've a Java class which are exactly the same but under 2 different namespaces and cannot be modified. I require to convert both of those classes into an internal pojo representation of mine. Is there a way I could do in a generic manner without copying the same code.

For ex:

```
com.namespace.first;

public ClassA {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

&

```
com.namespace.second;

public ClassA {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

Now I've a Pojo which needs to be filled in by values coming from `ClassA`:

```
com.namespace.third

public ClassC {
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private String d;
   private String e;
}
```

One option is:

```
public ClassC convert(com.namespace.first.ClassA classA) {
   return new ClassC(classA.getA(), classA.getB(), "c", "d");
}

public ClassC convert(com.namespace.second.ClassA classA) {
   return new ClassC(classA.getA(), classA.getB(), "c", "d");
}
```

Is there a different route I could use instead of having 2 convert methods which does exactly the same thing (While this example is simple, in my case it is a lot bigger)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
public <T> ClassC convert(T classA) {
   return new ClassC(classA.getA(), classA.getB(), "c", "d");
}
```

Comment: Yeah Initially I did think of that, but the issue is if we don't specify what the type of T is , the compiler doesn't know that T has properties a and b

Comment: @user1692342 well of course it does, when you call convert, the compiler will check that the class of the object you are passing, contains a method `getA()` and `getB()`... try to use this code and compile

Answer (score 0):

If you can use libraries then Apache BeanUtils has copyProperties method.

```
public static void copyProperties(Object dest, Object orig);
```

> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for
> all cases where the property names are the same.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-